# vertical navigation working not correctly in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, menu, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

Really getting some unwanted behaviour from IE7 and IE8 on header and fotter vertical menu. Did this before without problem but while using Wordpress it's just not getting it right.

Here is the test site: http://examples.iamwebsitedeveloper.com/walkinmyshoes/

And here is the code used for `#headerNav`:

```css
#headerNav {
    display:block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 940px;
    position: relative;
    z-index:99999;
    font: Verdana, sans-serif;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #894ba6;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #894ba6 0%, #743a8f 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#894ba6), color-stop(100%,#743a8f));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #894ba6 0%,#743a8f 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #894ba6 0%,#743a8f 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #894ba6 0%,#743a8f 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #894ba6 0%,#743a8f 100%);
    margin-bottom:20px;
    behaviour:url(PIE.htc);
}

.ie7 #headerNav,.ie8 #headerNav{*display: block;*zoom:1;}

#headerNav ul{
    font-size: 1.077em;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0px;
}

#headerNav li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    border-right:1px solid #8B4DA7;
}
```

Moreover if you look at the footer segment the background color and block is not coming!  Moreover the footer navigation is behaving the same way!

Using IE conditional classes as well as css3pie, I can't get it working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Evan Vai,
Strange problem when i opening the debugger and closing it the css comes back. Its may be the execution of jQuery.

Comment: Really Strange. JQuery shouldn't do that though! might be something else.... but not sure... anyone else?

Comment: Ok Matin, Good news...... Two different JQuery may be conflicting with each other..... because I was using boilerplate google ajax api with fallbacks and wordpress was inserting it's own on head!

I just included a a function so that jquery is been called only once. And its working! But not getting why it is relating with JQuery?